# Is this the right way of using an RF communication?

Tags: rf, remote-control

I have a [433Mhz Superheterodyne receiver](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Wholesale-433-Mhz-Superheterodyne-RF-Receiver-and-Transmitter-Module-ASK-kits-with-antenna-For-Arduino-Diy/32799575156.html) and a hand set remote of similar frequency, I'm using the [RC-Switch library](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch) and I couldn't find a better way than using the "numbers" that I'm receiving like this:

```cpp
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySwitch.enableReceive(0);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 7264305) {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
  if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 7264308) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 7264306) {
    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
  }
}
```

Is there any other (better?) way than just using the "numbers" simply like that or everyone are using their remote commands like I'm using?

Comment: all data is just numbers ... your transmission data appear to be 24 bits long ... for example decimal `7264305` translates to 24 bit binary `011011101101100000110001`, which can be described in hexadecimal as `6ED831` .... some of the bits are the switch states and the rest are probably a predetermined filler that could be used to check the validity of the transmission or they may be the address of the transmitter

Comment: for the received values of `7264305`, `7264306` and `7264308`, the last 4 bits of the received data are `0001`, `0010` and `0100` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits for this answer are mainly for jsotola (see his remarks above). But I want to show an alternative to the `if` statements, and a way to get the last 4 bits:

1. In case you want to check for the least significant bits, use `((mySwitch.getReceivedValue() & 0xFFFFF0)`
2. TO check for the least significant four bits (the data you want to act upon), use `((mySwitch.getReceivedValue() & 0xF)`
3. Use a switch statement instead of the `if` statement; also in theory (I don't know the code of `mySwitch.getReceivedValue()` does not need to be executed multiple times.

So you get something like this:

```
void loop() 
{
  unsigned long receivedValue = mySwitch.getReceivedValue(); // Call function only once

  if ((receivedValue & 0xFFFF0) == 0x6ED830)
  {
    // Process action
    switch (receivedValue & 0xF)
    {
    case 0x5:
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      break;

    case 0x8:
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      break;

    case 0x6:
      mySwitch.resetAvailable();
      break;

    default: // All other values
      break; // Ignore
  }
}
```